# Comparing models using Anova

Tags: r, anova

Im trying to compare 6 models using the Anova function. mod1:4 are made using the lm function and mod 5 and 6 are models made using the lmer function. I think this is whats causing this error message, any ideas how i can compare these 6 models?

```
anova(mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4, mod5, mod6)
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Comment: Using the anova function only makes sense if a) you are feeding it with the same kind of models, e.g. only lm models and b) the models should be nested/sequential, i.e. model 2 should include everything that model 1 has + e.g. new predictors, same goes for mod2 vs, mod 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anova()` *can* work with a mixture `lmer` and `lm` models.  However, due to the way that R's type system is set up, it only works if the *first argument is an `lmer` model*. That is, the `anova.merMod()` method (which gets called if the first argument is a `[g]lmer` model) knows how to deal with `lm` objects, but the `anova.lm()` method (which gets called if an `lm` object is first) doesn't know about `merMod` objects ...

```r
> library(lme4)
Loading required package: Matrix
> fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy, REML = FALSE)
> fm2 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, sleepstudy)
> fm3 <- lm(Reaction ~ 1, sleepstudy)
> anova(fm1, fm2, fm3)
Data: sleepstudy
Models:
fm3: Reaction ~ 1
fm2: Reaction ~ Days
fm1: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
    npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
fm3    2 1965.0 1971.4 -980.52   1961.0                          
fm2    3 1906.3 1915.9 -950.15   1900.3  60.756  1  6.461e-15 ***
fm1    4 1802.1 1814.8 -897.04   1794.1 106.214  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> anova(fm3, fm2, fm1)
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend comparing models using `compare_performance()` from `performance` package instead of `anova()`.

This way you can compare AIC, BIC, R-squared, and so on.

See the material here: https://easystats.github.io/performance/articles/compare.html

After visual comparison, I would recommend you using `test_performance()` from the same package.

I would also recommend you to rerun your models using the functions they recommend.